# Ok to have a form made only of submit buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any issue with having a form made up only of two submit buttons? It allows me to have a filter button without having to use javascript.

Here is my code example: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/928Dj/33/

```
<div>
    <ul id="filter">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any status &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="opt">
            <form>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Active" /></li>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Inactive" /></li>
            </form>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any date &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="opt">
            <form>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="date" value="Today" /></li>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="date" value="This Week" /></li>
            </form>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any time your curious about about whether some markup is valid, try http://validator.w3.org/check before asking questions on Stack Overflow. You'll get your answer much faster that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine, but your markup is otherwise quite invalid. You can't nest a `<form>` inside a `<ul>` without an `<li>` around it.

This is completely invalid:

```
<ul class="opt">
   <form>
     <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Active" /></li>
     <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Inactive" /></li>
   </form>
</ul>
```

You need to reverse the `<form>` and `<ul>` tags:

```
<form>
  <ul class="opt">
    <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Active" /></li>
    <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Inactive" /></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that this was invalid HTML.  Non-standard to be sure, but nothing in [the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) appears to tell me that a form can't exist inside a list.  'Twould be great if you could provide a reference!  :)

Comment: @Graham Feed it into the validator I linked you to. It's invalid. Nothing can existing directly inside a `<ul>` except an `<li>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: @Graham Also, the document you've linked is irrelevant. Look up the documentation for `<ul>`, not for `<form>`. Of course the restriction of which elements can appear inside a `<ul>` isn't in the `<form>` documentation.